# adding https:// in return statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding

I have a requirement where I need to return "https://hostname:port/context".

```
formulas: {
     url: function(get) {
          return get('protocol') + ':' + get('hostname') + ':' + get('port') + '/' + get('webcontext');
     }
}
```

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Ext.String.format`.I advise you to use the default values.

```
formulas: {
   url: function(get) {
       return Ext.String.format('{0}://{1}:{2}/{3}',
          get('protocol') || 'https',
          get('host') || 'localhost',
          get('port') || 80,
          get('context') || '')

   }
}
```